# Pass username from ViewBag to knockout viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, knockout.js, httpcontext

Trying to put some pieces together here.

**Piece 1**: I know that I can get the current username in MVC by using:

```
@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

in my razor view.

**Piece 2**: I have some MVVM-style code in a separate JS file, relevant parts shown below:

```
var FeedbackViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.username = ko.observable("");
    self.feedbackText = ko.observable("");
    self.userNameCaptured = ko.computed(function () { return self.username().length > 3; }, self);
};

var feedbackViewModel = new FeedbackViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(feedbackViewModel, document.getElementById("feedbackModal"));
```

**Question**: How do I pass the current username from MVC3 to the Knockout viewModel so that I can observe and take action based upon it?

Comment: I see the confusion, BTW: if you want to instantiate the ViewModel in the JS file itself, make it global (preferably in a namespace) so you can access it from the HTML. I prefer to do the instantiation in the HTML for this reason.

Answer (score 3):

I assume `feedbackViewModel` is defined as a global variable, so you could simply add some code to the CSHTML file to populate it inline:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
feedbackViewmodel.username("@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name");
</script>
```

Another option would be to pass the variable into the ViewModel function as a constructor element.

Comment: Hi Joel -- As I mentioned, my JavaScript is in a separate JS file and thus I think it's interpreted differently. Not entirely sure though; I'll have to check it out and see if I can get it to work that way too. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It shouldn't matter that the JavaScript is in a separate file, it still has to be imported into the HTML.  this means you should have access to the ViewModel object, in which case either of these would work.

Comment: Joel, I think it's clever. By injecting the Razor variable into the feedbackViewmodel you skip the added jquery selctor and exposing the value in dom source. The only downside I see is the call feedbackViewmodel.username("HttpContext....") has to be made from the individual view. You say it can be moved to a js file, but how would a js file interpret a Razor variable? Am I missing something?

Comment: PS +1 for this answer. I intend to refactor some of my code this way.

Comment: Dave: nothing is being hidden. The assumption is that the View has *runtime* access to the ViewModel instance defined in the JS file.  Razor is simply being used to write the JavaScript code in the HTML file, which gets called at runtime to set the observable property of the ViewModel.  This is mostly because Intellisense blows chunks when writing JS with Razor.  jQuery also has nothing to do with it as Knockout will handle the binding to the VM properties.

Answer (score 2):

(I'd rather post this as comment than answer but somehow don't have option here)

I've faced similar problems in the past (handoff between razor and javascript). The best answer I've found is to create a hidden control (#hiddenval or #username) which can then be "read" by a JQuery selector.

This approach works for me every time. It's inelegant and may potentially expose info to a user sourcing the html...

if it's not obvious, @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name should be populated as part of the markup

Comment: Hi Dave, I think this serves as a fine answer -- not the most desirable approach, but certainly an approach that works. I'll likely clean up / update this answer with some code when I've implemented it.

Comment: Goober, have you considered creating an action method (get) that returns it as a json object? I've done the advantage is data not being part of the DOM and less detectable.

The downside again, is an extra call to .NET from the browser.

Comment: In response to Joel's approach: it works pretty well but depends on your jscript residing on your view rather than a js file (as i suspect you have it organized). Still, you can utilize this approach if you populate a variable or constructor from your razor view.

Comment: Just to be clear, that is not accurate: you can easily put your ViewModel in a separate JS file. Think of it this way: the HTML *always* has to have access to the JS object, so all you are doing is accessing the JS object (defined in a JS file) in the HTML. Most likely, you are instantiating the ViewModel in the HTML, but even if the JS file creates it, the object still needs to be accessible from the HTML, so all you are doing is setting a property on the JS object.

Comment: @JoelCochran, yes I understood when you clarified my statement in your own answer 8 months ago. I gave a +1 to your comment and answer at the time.

Comment: Sorry Dave, that wasn't pointed at you, it was just for the benefit of any future readers.